# How to find a value of a point in a new coordinate system?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

[image]

The known data: **length of** $AO$, $OB$, **angles** $\alpha$, $\beta$, **point value** of $B= \left(b_1,b_2\right)$ in the Cartesian coordinate system where $O$ is the origin. It is also known that **point value** $O= \left(O_1,O_2\right)$ in the Cartesian coordinate system where $A$ is the origin

How can I find the value of a point $B= \left(b_{1new}, b_{2new}\right)$ in Cartesian coordinate system where $A$ is the origin? First I tried to use matrix and map points, but it did not work.

The Cartesian coordinate system with origin $O$ was moved from point $A$ to point $O$ and rotated clockwise through an angle $\alpha$.

Comment: Can't you just use trigonometry? The $x$-coordinate would be $AO \cos(\alpha) + OB \cos(\beta)$ and the $y$-component would be $AO \sin(\alpha)+ OB \sin(\beta)$.

Comment: @Fenris can you please explain why for x coordinate, you added OBcosβ (because the β isn't from the origin of A)?

Comment: Think of it as two triangles

Comment: @Fenris where the triangle of OB with angle β and also 90 degrees?

Comment: I am sorry. I see now that I misunderstood the illustration.

Comment: Are you sure this question is well-posed? It says nothing about the angular orientation of the two coordinate systems with respect to each other, which matters.

Comment: @Fenris the  cartesian coordinate system with origin O was moved from point A to point O and rotated an angle α clockwise

Comment: Okay. I think that was not obvious from the illustration. I suggest you divide the problem into parts: First find out how you translate between the standard coordinate system and one which is rotatet through the angle $\alpha$ clockwise. Then take the translation by $O$ into account.

Comment: Some input info is redundant.

Comment: The direction of B in the original system is $90-\alpha+\beta$

Comment: The labeling on the figure shows $\alpha$ as the angle of the direction the frame is translated. The angle of rotation is not indicated on the figure at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: coordinate system transformation]

We provide you with a diagram depicting the coordinate system transformation described in your problem statement. The coordinate system, which has $O_0 = A=(0,0)$ as its origin, is shown in $\mathrm{\mathbf{\color{red}{red}}}$. The same coordinate system after translation, which is also drawn in $\mathrm{\mathbf{\color{red}{red}}}$, has its origin at $O=(o_\mathrm{x}, o_\mathrm{y})$. This coordinate system is then subjected to a clockwise rotation to obtain the coordinate system drawn in $\mathrm{\mathbf{\color{green}{green}}}$.

We leave it to OP to obtain the sought expressions for the coordinates of point $B=\left(b_\mathrm{xnew}, b_\mathrm{ynew}\right) $ with respect to a coordinate system having its origin at $A=\left(0, 0\right)$. First, you have to find the angle $\measuredangle BON$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Then, express $QB$ and $BN$ in terms of $OA$, $OB$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$.